# Split output of cat command into separate lines

Tags: bash, split, cat

I have a trouble with splitting output of **cat** command (`cat /proc/meminfo`) into separate lines for working with them.

```
#!/bin/bash
CURR_DUMP=$(cat /proc/meminfo)
arrIN=(${CURR_DUMP// kB/})

for t in "${arrIN[@]}"
do
echo $t
done

exit 0
```

But instead of separate lines I have a mess of parts of each line.
What's going wrong with my solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you planning to achieve?

Comment: I want to filter some interesting lines using a loop (or just use some lines by their indices in an array) and build custom output of memory usage as a result.

Comment: Your question is still not very clear. But I am certain that the `mapfile` solution mentioned below is the suggested method to do this. But it is worth investigating what happens with `CURR_DUMP=$(cat /proc/meminfo)`. It actually gives you a string to process and if you wish to strip the `kB`s at the end `arrIN=(${CURR_DUMP// kB/})` will not do what you want.. :) Good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mapfile`:

```
mapfile -t arr < <(sed 's/ kB$//' /proc/meminfo)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!